# Wireless card issues with Ubuntu and Broadcom bc4312

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, broadcom

So I have a Dell Inspiron 1526 that has a broadcom bcm4312 wireless card. I installed Ubuntu and (big surprise) the wireless card isn't working.

No problem for a hot shot like me who has fixed this same problem before on my old laptop. Just install bc43xx-fwcutter and install the firmware, well it didn't work. Needless to say I've been googleing for more than an hour and I'm tuff out of luck.

So how can I get this to work?

Oh, one minor note: I don't have anyway to connect to the internet on said computer because all I have is wireless that is being pick upped from across the street (no ethernet), but I do have another computer that can connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [Ndiswrapper](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper) and the windows drivers not work? I have always had good luck with this solution.
caveat? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=867487

Comment: Thats what I ended up doing. It works pretty well except that I had to write a shell script to do `modprobe` every startup.